# What is proper term for 'composure' when mentioning it as your strength?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In reference to your strengths and weakness. How to well describe composure as your strength. I am looking for a word/strength that represent ability to not to panic in any situation(especially difficult one).

Comment: *Composure* already includes the sense of "not to panic" and can be considered a strength. Is there a reason you wish to use a different term?

Comment: If it can be considered as strength itself, then I guess it answers my question. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Equanimity may not be so different from composure, but from the definitions I've checked it mentions an extra detail of remaining composed in the face of difficulty or hardship, which is not something I've seen for definitions of "composure".

> n. composure, esp. under tension or strain; evenness of temper.
>
> Noun 1.   equanimity - steadiness of mind under stress;
>  [The Free
>   Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Equanimity)
>
> Calmness and composure, especially in a difficult situation. ‘she
>   accepted both the good and the bad with equanimity’>br> [Oxford Living
>   Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/equanimity)
>
> Equanimity
>  a state of psychological stability and composure which
>   is undisturbed by experience of or exposure to emotions, pain, or
>   other phenomena that may cause others to lose the balance of their
>   mind.
>  [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equanimity)

I'm not sure if this extra semantic detail is commonplace or not.

Also, there is another word I like:

imperturbability
I like it because the prefixes un-, in-, im-, meaning "not" seem to imply a strength in many cases, like impregnable, impermeable, impeccable, impervious, invincible, unconquerable etc.

> imperturbable adj. Unshakably calm and collected. 
> [American Heritage
>   Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/imperturbability)
>
> imperturbable
>  adjective
>  Unable to be upset or excited;
>   calm.
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/imperturbable)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "**level-headed**". (It may also be spelled without the hyphen as "levelheaded", or as two words "level headed".)

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/level-headed):

> **Adjective**
>
> 1. (idiomatic) Sensible; rational; possessing sound judgment.
>
>    - 1909, Ralph Connor, *The Foreigner*, ch. 7:
>
>      > I urge you to weigh calmly, deliberately, as cool, **level-headed** Canadians, the evidence produced by the prosecution.
>
> **Usage notes**
>
> - Often having the connotation of remaining calm, composed, and careful, of not acting out of reflex or excessive emotion.

From [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/level-headed), which quotes Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014:

> even-tempered, balanced, and reliable; steady

In my experience the term works well when talking about how one is being rational and making calm, collected, wise choices even in a stressful or difficult situation.

Answer (score 0):

**face up to**. [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/face+up+to)

> face it, confront or accept an unpleasant or difficult situation.

As in:

> I knew the gentleman could face up to the difficult tasks at hand.